# Converting multiple arrays into a single hash

Tags: ruby, parsing, hashmap

I'm working on a configuration file parser and I need help parsing key: value pairs into a hash.

I have data in the form of: `key: value key2: value2 another_key: another_value`.

So far I have code in form of

```
    line = line.strip!.split(':\s+')
```

which returns an array in the form of

```
["key:value"]["key2: value2"]["another_key: another_value"]
```

How can I turn these arrays into a single hash in the form of

```
{key=>value, key2=>value2, another_key=>another_value}
```

I'm not sure if the key:value pairs need to be in the form of a string or not. Whatever is easiest to work with.

Thanks for your help!

---

This is the solution I found:

```
    line = line.strip.split(':')
    hash = Hash[*line]
```

which results in the output`{"key"=>"value"}, {"key2"=>"value2"}`

Comment: Have a look at [String#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-partition).  That would be ideal for splitting each string into key and value, or use a regex with a capture group on each side of the colon.

Comment: Ah nice, String#partition is a useful method! Thanks @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very very close to Cary's solution:

```
Hash[*line.delete(':').split]
```

Comment: That's why I still felt it was worth adding.

Comment: Ah, the price of honesty. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
Hash[*line.gsub(':',' ').split]
  # => {"key"=>"value", "key2"=>"value2", "another_key"=>"another_value"}
```

Comment: Good solution, I used this to come up with something of my own

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the key and value are single words, I'd probably do something like this:

```
Hash[line.scan(/(\w+):\s?(\w+)/)]
```

You can change the regex if it's not quite what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Nigel this works, but I'd rather not deal with the RegEx